# Streamplot of an ODE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm trying to make a streamplot of

$\qquad \frac{dy}{dx}=|y(x)|$

together with a couple of streamlines. I got stuck in the syntax. Can anyone help me out of it?

This what I've done:

```
sp = StreamPlot[{1, Abs[y[x]]}, {x, 0, 4}, {y[x], -4, 4}];
sol = y /. ParametricNDSolve[{y'[x] == Abs[y[x]], y[0] == a}, y, {x, 0, 4}, a]; 
Manipulate[
  Show[
    sp, 
    Plot[Evaluate[sol[a][x]], {x, 0, 4}, 
      PlotStyle -> Red, 
      PlotRange -> Full], 
    Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, a}]}], 
  {a, 0, 4}]
```

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Please post your code...

Comment: This was most welcome :) Apparantely I have a steep learning curve. One question. In the code below how can I make thick red lines?sol = DSolve[{Q'[t] == 2 - 2/3*Q[t], Q[0] == q0}, Q[t], t]
Show[Plot[
  Evaluate[Table[Q[t] /. sol /. {q0 -> i}, {i, 0, 4, 1}]], {t, 0, 6}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Red, Red, Red}], 
 StreamPlot[{1, 2 - 2/3*Q[t]}, {t, 0, 6}, {Q[t], 0, 6}, 
  StreamMarkers -> "PinDart", StreamStyle -> Gray], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "Q(t)"}, PlotRange -> All]

Answer (score 4):

Use `StreamPlot`

```
sp = StreamPlot[{1, Abs[y]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

```
sol[y0_?NumericQ] := 
 NDSolve[{D[y[x], x] == Abs[y[x]], y[0] == y0}, y, {x, -5, 5}]     

scp = Plot[Evaluate[{y[x]} /. sol[#] & /@ Range[0, 20, 0.3]], {x, -3, 3}, 
      PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 8, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, PlotStyle -> Red]

Show[sp,scp ]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but I would like to see a use of e.g NDSolve together with some boundary conditions

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that in your question, @user.